# Visual C: language modes specified are incompatible

Tags: c, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

Using VisualStudio 2019 on C code:

When I set the C language spec to anything but Legacy...

[image]

...then I get:

[image]

I tried different combos of C++/C specs (even though I only have C files, so C++ should not matter) but I always get this error.

Annoyingly, the error tells me very little. **WHICH** modes are incompatible? How can I get a more verbose error out of the compiler?

At the very least, it could tell me which flags not to mix.
This is the command line:

```
/GS /W3 /Zi /Od /fp:precise /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /WX- /std:c11 /Gd /MDd /Fa"x64\Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Debug\" /Fp"x64\Debug\turboledzservice.pch" /diagnostics:column
```

Comment: A guess ... It doesn't like `/std:c11` on the command line even if it's the same as the menu item. If you leave off the command line option, what happens? Or, use legacy menu option and add `/std:c11` Does the test program have something in it that is _only_ valid with c11 or higher (e.g. `stdatomic.h` and some of the functions)? Then, you _know_ it's in the correct mode. Yes, it _should_ tell you which options it doesn't like. But, it is MS after all ;-) You could write a script that loops and adds [or subtracts] options one-by-one. Or, a binary search of some sort.

Comment: That's a very obscure bug.  What it really means is that the front-end of the compiler (c1.dll) doesn't agree with the back-end of the compiler (c2.dll) about what language to compile for.  Nobody else has this problem, surely it will go away when you update Visual Studio.  Pick at least version 16.9, currently it's at 16.11.26

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this problem comes up if you have something like

```
<LanguageStandard>...</LanguageStandard>
```

in a Linux C++ project. It gets fixed if you disable the `LanguageStandard` for Linux projects.

(Note that this is not the same as `CppLanguageStandard`, used for Linux projects.)